# Hilbert spaces: $\|{w}\| = \sup \lbrace |\operatorname{Re}(\langle{w,v}\rangle)\vert : {\|{v}\|\leqslant{1}} \rbrace $

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Why in a Hilbert space does the norm of a vector $w$ satisfy the following?

$\|{w}\| = \sup \lbrace |\operatorname{Re}(\langle{w,v}\rangle)\vert : 
{\|{v}\|\leqslant{1}} \rbrace $

Comment: $|\langle w,v \rangle | \le ||w|| ||v||\le ||w||$ by the CS inequality.  This is half the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Riesz representation theorem we have that every functional  $f \in H^*$ is of the form $f(x)=<x,u>$ for some $u \in H$ and $||f||=||u||$

Also from the consequences of Hahn-Banach:

> If $x \in X$ where $X$ is a normed space,we have that $||x||=\sup\{|f(x)|:||f|| \leq 1\}$

Now $||w||=\sup\{|f(w)|:||f|| \leq 1\}=\sup\{|<w,u>|:||u|| \leq 1\}$

But $\Re z \leq |z|$ thus $$|<w,u>| \geq \Re<w,u> \Rightarrow ||w||=\sup\{|<w,u>|:||u|| \leq 1\} \geq \sup\{\Re<w,u>:||u|| \leq 1\}$$ $(1)$

Also from Cauchy-Swartz we have that $$\Re|<w,u>|\leq |<w,u>| \leq ||u||||w||\Rightarrow  \sup\{\Re<w,u>:||u|| \leq1\} \leq ||w||$$ $(2)$

Combining $(1),(2)$ we have that

> $$\sup\{\Re<w,u>:||u|| \leq 1\}=||w||$$